# Make browser get url from server if not in Angular route

Tags: angularjs

I have an Angular 1.5 SPA using html5mode and I'd like the browser to fetch a url if it's not in the routeProvider.

**Example:** 
**/** is the index of the site. **/test** is on the server and not in an Angular route.  If I'm on **/** and click a link to **/test** I'd like to simply load **/test**.

In other words. If I'm in my Angular app I'd like to use the routes but fallback to the server if there are none (rather than to redirect to some internal url).

Any idea on how to do that without using separate domains?

Comment: Is it possible you do not have your server side set up properly for html5Mode? This link is for UI router, but covers the same issue. https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-configure-your-server-to-work-with-html5mode

Comment: It goes to a nonexisting SPA url when I go to /test, then works fine (gets the url from the server) when I refresh the browser (at /test).

Answer (score 0):

if you are using `ui-router`, it provides an event called `$stateNotFound` fired when a requested state cannot be found using the provided state name during transition. You could send request to server in this event handler

```
$scope.$on('$stateNotFound', function(event, unfoundState, fromState, fromParams){
        event.preventDefault() //first abort this transition

        console.log(unfoundState.to);
        console.log(unfoundState.toParams);
        console.log(unfoundState.options);

        window.location.href = '...';
})
```